# Do employers on SO Careers have the ability to send out bulk messages?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs

I have SO Careers profile and I got an inbox message that stated:

> I was looking at your profile on StackOverflow Careers, and really
>   like the looks of your experience, as well as some of your
>   StackOverflow tech answers.

Will it be safe to assume that the author actually may have never visited my profile but instead made a wide search and then sent this mass mailing to all matching entries?

Does the site afford employers such bulk functionality?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Without more details, it's hard to state exactly what's happening in your scenario.

In general though, employers would be unable to send bulk messages to developers through Stack Overflow Careers. A few reasons:

1. **The current interface doesn't allow it.** You just can't send messages to more than one person at a time.
2. **You can't select multiple people to message at the same time.** You have to view a developer's profile to select the "Message" button.
3. **We take reported messaging abuse seriously.** If people report abuse of the messaging system or "spammy" messages, we take those reports seriously and look into them. If we find the reports true, we talk to those companies. Our initial goal is to help those companies to get better. If that doesn't work, then we explore other avenues.
4. **We cap all employers to sending no more than 20 messages at a time.** All employers. No exceptions. You can't even purchase a higher limit. [From our FAQ for Employers:](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/faq)

> **Why can I only have 20 outstanding messages?**
>   Limiting the number of outstanding messages helps us control spam sent
>   to candidates and encourages employers to keep messages relevant to a
>   candidate’s interest, experience and qualifications. Once a candidate
>   replies, or after 7 days if they do not reply, a message spot is freed
>   up.

Comment: My question is **not** about spamming or any other type of abuse.  I am just trying to figure out why my profile was tagged for the opportunity that I am not a good match for.  So my *assumption* was that it was just a part of a broad campaign.

Comment: Ok? It seems your assumption was wrong.

Comment: The only question I see is "Does the site afford employers such bulk functionality?" My answer addresses that. Again without knowing specifics, it could be the employer is a) mistaken about you being a good fit, b) confused about something in your profile, or c) sees something in your profile that makes them think you're a potential fit for this job.

Comment: I never knew about any of this message throttling. You should probably advertise it more. It would make me respond more quickly to peoples request (even if it was a no) and also give a little more consideration to a request knowing it was cherry picked.

Comment: If an employer sends me a message and includes a link to set up an appointment, would I also need to reply within SO Careers in order to free up a message for them?

Comment: @JenR Once you have accepted (or rejected) to talk with an employer, the message is released back to the employer. Our goal with the 20 message limit is to keep employers from bulk messaging the CV database. Once you have responded, we consider the handshake complete.

Comment: @Ian Good point. Thanks for the feedback. I'll pass this along to the rest of the product team.

Comment: @Ian: Never knew about this limit either, and (as a candidate) I like!

Comment: Thanks @Hynes. It sounds like you guys are putting a lot of effort into it. I'll be honest I don't user the careers site that much (although I'm not actually looking for work), maybe I should do

Comment: Thanks @Hynes - The link in question is an external link though (to youcanbook.me), so I am not sure how the system would know whether I have responded.

Comment: Eww, you are missing a serial comma in that FAQ answer.

Comment: @Tyler: It's fine the way it is.

Comment: So each employer can send out ~2.86 messages/day if they are pure spam and ignored.  And cannot increase this number without creating a "ghost employer" account?  If they spammed the top SO accounts blindly, they could contact the top ~1044 accounts each year.  The OP is the ~6000th account this year.  If the spammer's criteria was so loose that 25% of accounts would pass it, and they have been running for 2 years, and the overlap between successive year top accounts is 50%, they could reach ~6000 by year 2.